# How to add a new item through code in visual studio 2015 community?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I want to add a new webpage through code. Normally we would just right click and select add new item, but i want to know if there's a way that i can just code to add new items. The reason why i wanted to know about this is because i'm trying to create a content management system, and it requires to create a new webpage. Since the user does not know how to create it in visual studio 2015, I will need to create a system where the user can create their own webpage via the actual website. Like for example: I wanted to add new webpage called "Test.aspx" in my Pages folder. The question is how can i do it in code? Hope this makes sense.

**Normally, we would add items like the picture below.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do using Visual Studio , is not designed for.

Visual studio is used for writing code and not as a content management system.

How ever , if you would like to use ASP.NET content management , then there are providers such as :

[Umbarco](https://umbraco.com/) or [Sitecore](http://www.sitecore.net/)

Comment: I see..so all i have to do is manually create a webpage using the normal way like Add->Add New Item?.

Answer (score 0):

I sense security issue if visual studio allow creation of source file programmatically, that's what I thought at first.

But I came across this link afteerwards:
http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/170_Creating_ASPX_Page_Dynamically_in_ASPNet.aspx

And it seems like possible.